# XSL not working, XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: xml, xslt

I seem to have a problem with my XML file. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../xsl.xsl"?>

<centru>
    <bicicleta>
        <numar>3</numar>
        <model>Copii</model>
        <accesorii>Casca</accesorii>
    </bicicleta>

    <bicicleta>
        <numar>8</numar>
        <model>Adulti</model>
        <accesorii>Cosulet</accesorii>
    </bicicleta>

    <bicicleta>
        <numar>2</numar>
        <model>Adulti</model>
        <accesorii>Cosulet</accesorii>
    </bicicleta>

    <bicicleta>
        <numar>6</numar>
        <model>Doua Persoane</model>
        <accesorii>Fara Acc.</accesorii>
    </bicicleta>

    <bicicleta>        
        <numar>5</numar>
        <model>Adulti</model>
        <accesorii>Cosulet</accesorii>
    </bicicleta>

    <orar>
        <luni_vineri>08:00 - 18:00</luni_vineri>
        <sambata>10:00 - 16:00</sambata>
        <duminica> Inchis </duminica>
    </orar>

    <contact>
        <adresa>Splaiul Independentei nr. 290</adresa>
        <telefon tip="mobil">0765432100</telefon>
        <email>inchirieri@bicicleta.ro</email>
    </contact>
</centru>
```

And this is the code for my XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <table width="300px\" align="center\" cellpadding="0\" cellspacing="0\" border="1\" style="background-color:66FFFF;font-family:verdana;font-size:10pt;border:1\">
                <tr>
                    <td  width="100px\"  align="center\" >Luni-Vineri</td>
                    <td width="100px\" align="center\">Sambata</td>
                    <td  width="100px\"  align="center\" >Duminica</td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="centru/bicicleta">
                    <tr>
                        <td  width="100px"  align="center"   >
                            <xsl:value-of select="numar"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="300px" align="center" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="model"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="300px" align="center" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="accesorii"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.
```

The document tree is shown below. I have a reference pointing to my .xsl file, but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: When you say `document tree`, do you mean the xml file? Nothing is below.

Comment: Areyou sure you the **xsl.xsl** is in the correct folder? According to your XML it should be in the parent folder of where the xml file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the xml and xsl on my computer and it worked when I put the xsl on the same level with xml. It didnot want to work when I have put it one level up. If it is possible for you, do the same. This that you will have

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xsl"?>
```

instead of:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../xsl.xsl"?>
```